# Creating laravel not working

Tags: php, laravel

Hi there this is my view:

```
<form role="form" class="form" action="{{ url('/users/settings/notifications/notifications-settings') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ csrf_field() }}   
<input type="checkbox"  class="flat-orange" name="notification_type1" value="1" @if(in_array(1,$user_notifications ) == 1)checked @endif>
<input type="checkbox"  class="flat-orange" name="notification_type2" value="2" @if(in_array(2, $user_notifications ) == 2)checked @endif>
<input type="checkbox"   class="flat-orange" name="notification_type3" value="3" @if(in_array(3, $user_notifications ) == 3)checked @endif>
<input type="checkbox"  class="flat-orange" name="notification_type4" value="4" @if(in_array(4,$user_notifications ) == 4)checked @endif>
  <button type="submit" class="btn save-lang">@lang('buttons.save_changes')</button>
  </form>
```

Here I have my routes:

```
 Route::get('/settings/notifications/notifications-settings', 'UserSettingController@getNotificationsSettings');

 Route::post('/settings/notifications/notifications-settings', 'UserSettingController@setNotificationsSettings');
```

Here I have my controller:
class UserSettingController extends Controller

```
{
    public function getNotificationsSettings(){

        $user_notifications = UserNotificationType::select('notification_type')->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()->toArray();

        $user_notifications = array_map(function($user_notifications){
          return  $user_notifications['notification_type'];
        }, $user_notifications);


          return view('website.settings.notifications.notifications-settings')->with(['user_notifications' => $user_notifications]);

  } 

     public function setNotificationsSettings( Request $request){

                for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {

                  $update_user_notifications = UserNotificationType::create([

                    'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
                    'notification_type'      => $request['notification_type'.$i] ?? false

                  ]);
                  dd( $update_user_notifications);

                }

return redirect()->back()->with(['status' => 'Notification Settings updated successfully.']);



      }

}
```

Model:

```
public $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'notification_type',
    ];
```

I need to be able after creating once the second time to be able to update that not create 4 others I need this to do on the same function 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXGTy.png)

Can someone please help me I am new on coding, is there any way to achieve what I want ..

Comment: When a checkbox is null it is not sent to the server, only when its true, try `$request['notification_type'.$i] ?? false`?

Comment: Do a `dd($request)` to see what the request contains. Everithing seems to be ok at a first glance. Second: you could use radio buttons since you only have 1 option

Comment: You can set the field in your DB nullable, you can also add this to the validation, you can also add it in your migration by chaining ->nullable(); onto the field in question

Comment: @Quezler I edited my code to ?? false, but now it creates plus 4 every time i change I need to be able the second time only to update

Answer (score 0):

In database table structure allow null on `notification_type` column

```
ALTER TABLE user_notification_types CHANGE notification_type notification_type INT(11) NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use eloquent relations.

On User model:

```
    public $timestamps = false;

```
protected $fillable = [
    'user_id',
    'notification_type',
];

public function notificationTypes () {
    return $this->hasMany(UserNotificationType::class);
}
```

```

Then in you `setNotificationsSettings` you can do this:

```

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 4; $i++) {
    $notificationTypes[] = $request['notification_type' . $i];
}

$user = Auth::user();
$user->notificationTypes()->sync(notificationTypes);
```

```

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many